# AngularJS - how to find uncompiled dom elements inserted by 3P javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an AngularJS app combined with some legacy javascript that does DOM manipulation. The messy part - sometimes the legacy javascript inserts dom elements *with AngularJS directives*. Naturally AngularJS is not aware of this, and these directives are not compiled and linked to a scope. How to compile and link the directives on the new elements that are dynamically inserted?

Please don't tell me to re-write everything in angular, or wrap legacy stuff in angular, I can't touch that. My angularjs app is a plugin that runs on 3P websites to give extra functionality.

Options I have considered:

1. Just tear down the angular app and bootstrap it again each time - this is actually very difficult to do cleanly because there is no clean method to tear down the app: [How to destroy an angularjs app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14990480/how-to-destroy-an-angularjs-app)
2. Traverse the dom looking for uncompiled directives. I only have a handful of directives to look for (as attributes). Angular automatically places ng-scope class on elements where scopes are attached, so if this is missing I can compile the directive manually use the $compile service and link it to the scope.

At the moment I am working on the second method, but I keep thinking there must be a smarter way. Please does anyone have a better idea?

I should mention that my app receives a callback after any dom manipulation - but it would be better if I didn't need it.

Comment: google `dom mutation observers` .... not available directly in older browsers but will defintiely help and there are some libraries that can help with various browsers